# Multiple *Types* of Validation on one cell (Stop & Information) - MS Excel

Tags: ms-office, validation

There are several questions and answers that I have found relating to applying multiple validation rules to a single cell, and all recommendations point to combining your rules into a single formula. This has the result that you get the same outcome/error message regardless of which validation rule is violated.

I would like functionality that follows the following rules:

- If the users enters a number which is not an integer between 1-5 (inclusive), STOP condition - this is never allowed under any circumstances, so prevent the data from being entered.
- If the user enters a number which is not recommended (based on other data), INFORMATION condition - warn the user that they may wish to re-think, but *do* allow the data to be entered.

An example spreadsheet that would demonstrate the correct functionality would be:

- A value is entered in Cell A1
- Cell A2 *does not allow* users to enter any number which is not 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.
- Cell A2 provides a *warning* if the user enters the same value as that in A1

Can this be done?

Comment: how many cells would the rule be applied to ? if it is just once cell you could use vba case to change the validation rule each time the cell value changes perhaps, if it is multiple cells thew rule is to apply to it may be a lot more difficult if possible at all

Comment: It's a whole column on a sheet with hundreds of lines, and needs to be able to tolerate that range growing or shrinking, and lines being inserted or removed midway between... I have VBA functions in place to keep all the validation and conditional formatting from becoming fragmented so am not against VBA if required. How would this switching work? I got the feeling the invalid popup only appears when a human types the data, and VBA can put any value in the cell valid or not without a popup?